# Read text file data that is separated by 3 spacing

Tags: python, csv, split, notepad

Hi i am trying to extract out the information on Column [3] and [4] at row 180. Problem i am facing is

1. Element is separated by 3 spaces
2. The @@Data starts at row 180
3. The code I am using can't extract out the specific Column
4. Error it give me: line = reader[180][3] IndexError: list index out of range

   ```
   @@Data: Source 0 in text format:        
   1    2    2    1    1    9    1    1    -2    2    1    -3    3    1 
   3    2    2    1    1    9    1    1    -2    2    1    -3    3    1 
   4    2    2    1    1    9    1    1    -1    1    1    -2    2    1
   ```

## Code i am using

```
     reader = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '))
     SatIP, CoerIP = getSatHcoer(reader)
     print SatIP, CoerIP

     def getSatHcoer(reader): 
     line = reader[180][3]
     Sat = line.split('    ')
     Sat =  Sat[len(Sat)-1]
     line = reader[180][4]
     Coer = line.split('     ')
     Coer =  Coer[len(Coer)-1] 
     return Sat, Coer
     pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are having trouble splitting the fields because they are separated by *3* spaces; you can actually split on regular expressions, try using:

```
 Coer = line.split("\s+")
```

`\s` is the regular expression class that represents whitespace (tabs, spaces, newlines, and backspaces?)
`+` means apply the previous pattern *one or more times*, so this expression will match one or more space characters. Using this method, it shouldn't matter how many spaces separate fields.

**EDIT** 
As mentioned below this only works if you import re and use re.split.

```
 import re
 Coer = re.split("\s+",line)
```

Comment: In Python you need to `import re` and use `re.split("\s+", line)`

Comment: Thank you i did import re and tried "\s+" But it still give me an empty result after i used print Coer,Sat

Comment: I believe that you'd need to `import re` and use `re.split(r' +', line)` for that method to work.

Comment: I got it worked! Yup Every Columns is separated by 3 spacing thus i used reader[180][6] to display the result.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that python indexing starts from 0, I'm assuming that when you say line 180, you mean the 181st line in the file and column 3 & 4 are the 4th and 5th columns in the file. If not, -1 from those numbers.

```
def getSatHcoer(reader):
    Sat = reader[180][3]
    Coer = reader[180][4]
    return Sat, Coer

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = [[x.strip().split('   ')] for x in f]
SatIP, CoerIP = getSatHcoer(reader)
print SatIP, CoerIP
```